# SQL query has me a little confused with joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 values which i need to query a table, which returns an ID from that table to then query another table to get a name, but i have no idea how the join thing works and am getting myself all confused. What I am trying to do is as follows;

```
$ID = 400
$ItemID = 300


Table: Items
---

where - Items.ID = $ID
where - Items.ItemID = $ItemID

Return: Items.SourceID


Table: Source
---

where - Source.ID = Items.SourceID

Return: Source.Name
```

The 2 values I have is at the top, then using those 2 values, i need to query the Items table to return the source.id, then query the Source table to get its actual name.

My 'failing' query is as follows;

```
SELECT Items.ID, Items.ItemID, Source.ID, Source.Name
FROM Items
INNER JOIN Source ON Source.ID = Source.ID
```

Any help to get this going would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "What I am trying to do is as follows;"  What follows makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

`Source ON Source.ID = Source.ID` is likely your problem, based on your explanation you may want to try:

```
SELECT Items.ID, Items.ItemID, Source.ID, Source.Name
FROM Items
INNER JOIN Source ON Source.ID = Items.SourceID
```

Comment: Would there need to be a WHERE in there somewhere for the inital values?

Comment: I don't believe so unless you are wanting to limit your results to anything specific. The join above returns all rows from the ```Items``` table and the ```Source``` table where the ```Source.ID``` matches the ```Items.SourceID```.

Comment: Are you trying to get all rows where the ```SourceID = 400``` or the ```ItemID = 300```?